# AJAX results not sticking to DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I have a successful AJAX request and results.  The result is simple text that I want to put in a table row within the DOM.  Below is the code:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var results = xhr.responseText;
      var col = document.getElementById("tr_concept_0_1_32").getElementsByClassName("col_1")[0];
      col.innerHTML = results;
    }
    else {
      console.log(event);
      alert("something went wrong!: " + event);
    }
  };
```

When I `return col.innerHTML = results;` I can see the DOM being modified but then it quickly reverts to its previous value.

I am new to AJAX so I'm not quite sure why the 'new value' is not sticking to the DOM.
Any suggestions?

**MORE CODE:**
**UPDATED button**

```
form.form-search(id='searchForm')
      fieldset
        .input-append
          input.input-xxlarge.search-query#search(type='text', placeholder='Search', name='q')
          button.btn.submit(onclick='getParams(); return false;') Search
```

The above is the code that is doing the work.  The user clicks on the form's `button`.  Could this be the problem?  I'm not handling something correct from this end?

**UPDATED button**
The above code works fine in Chrome but is not working in Firefox.
In Firefox, the post returns `success` but the `onreadystatechange` does not trigger.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `return` in the `onreadystatechange` method. Is there a reason you are?

Comment: no... just JS habit I suppose.  Just removed it.  Same issue.

Comment: What other code is running on your page? Nothing in the posted snippet will revert it.

Comment: Do you happen to be executing several of these AJAX requests around the same time? Or is it really just 1 that you're testing?

Comment: nothing... just trying to get a simple example working... minimal code

Comment: @Ian Just one AJAX request.  Using Node.js with Jade.  The Ajax successfully receives the `res.send("text")` from the server.  The DOM changes and then reverts back to the original value

Comment: I think the button is sending the AJAX, **and** submitting the form...therefore "reloading" the page - you see the value reset. If your button is only ever going to submit AJAX, change its `type` attribute to "button", OR use `onclick='getParams();return false;'` for its `onclick` handler.

Comment: @Ian So for my button I have `button.btn.submit(onclick="getParams(); return false;") Search`  This works in chrome but it's not working for firefox.

Comment: @Ian answered the question.  If you put it in the answers I can upvote you.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the button is sending the AJAX, **and** submitting the form...therefore "reloading" the page - so you see the value "reset".

If your button is only ever going to submit AJAX, change its `type` attribute to "button", OR use `onclick='getParams();return false;'` for its `onclick` handler.

There are other ways to do the same, but in my suggestion, using `return false;` prevents the default behavior of the submit button - submitting. But since it's after `getParams();`, `getParams` is still called and does what you need - the AJAX.

If you changed the `type` attribute to "button", it wouldn't even have the behavior of submitting, therefore not having this problem.